# Need Help reversing array

Tags: c

What I need is a user to input 10 integers separated by spaces and then prints that out reverse. This is what I have, but it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int a[ 9 ], i, j, t ; 
printf("Enter ten integers seperated by spaces:\n");

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}

j = i - 1;
i = 0;
while (i < j)
{
  t = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = t;
  i++;
  j--;
}

printf("\nReverse array is:\n");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++);
{
printf("%d ", a[i]);
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is the output of current program?

Comment: @Bill  If you need to input 10 numbers then the array has to be declared as having 10 elements. And to output an array in the reverse order there is no need to reverse the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two problems.

1. Your array, `a`, only has 9 elements. You should make it large enough to to contain all ten elements.
2. The second `for` loop has a trailing semicolon:

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++);
   {

This semicolon will cause the loop to behave like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) { }
{
```

Which isn't what you want.

Comment: Another thing to consider: you don't actually need to reverse the elements in your array in order to print the numbers in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You have define array `a[9]`.
Size of array is actually 10 so this should be like `a[10]`.

Remember when you define array, you have to specify the SIZE not a LAST INDEX.